# Develop Wordpress site with blog page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a wordpress site and I want it to have a blog page that uses wordpress functions that can easily fetch blog posts. I already have a blog page set up. An example is of BLOG POST 1 is:

```
BLOG POST 1
*Posted January 17, 2012*
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam...Continue reading →
```

When I click continue reading, it went to the baseUrl/slug(posted blog), but the display is is my home page... ; The url is correct but the display is not. It should display the selected blog post, but it displays my home page instead. Is there anything I need to configure on my front-end(CMS interface) or with my template file or with my blog?

Comment: please provide url which is showing in the browser and code for creating the url. otherwise it is tough to give the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you haven't provided the code which is creating the link. so I can't give you exact solution. But you may try the following code with modification. it may help you

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>" class="more">Read full article</a>
```

Remember, this code is under the loop.

Answer (score 0):

This can depend on so many variables, that it is way to complicated to explain here, especially with no code provided or URL .

try switching themes , or switch to the default wordpress theme .
THe display of blog , home or any other feature depends on your theme file ,
you might want to play a bit with wordpress, and read some basic tutorials in order to understand a bit more .